# Copy and paste from other workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to copy all the cells that contain blue font and copy in another workbook in the same range of the source, but im lost at this point. Everytime that i try to run this code, i get an run-time error.

```
 Sub test2()

 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.Calculation = xlManual

     Dim FonteA As Workbook, FonteB As Workbook
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim vFile As Variant

     Dim rCell As Range
     Dim lColor As Long
     Dim rColored As Range

     'Set source workbook
     Set FonteB = ActiveWorkbook
     'Open the target workbook
     vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
     'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
     If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
     Workbooks.Open vFile
     'Set targetworkbook
     Set FonteA = ActiveWorkbook

     FonteB.Worksheets("USD - SCHEDULE A").Activate
         lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

 Cells.CurrentRegion.Select
     Set rColored = Nothing
     For Each rCell In Selection
     If rCell.Font.Color = lColor Then
        If rColored Is Nothing Then
                 Set rColored = rCell
        Else
            Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
If rColored Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No cells match the color"
Else
    rColored.Select
    rColored.Copy

End If
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rColored = Nothing

FonteA.Worksheets("Matriz_Produto").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
FonteA.Worksheets("Matriz_Produto").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the runtime error?

Comment: Automation Error -2147221080 (800401a8)

Comment: Which line throws it?

Comment: FonteB.Worksheets("USD - SCHEDULE A").Activate

Comment: Still not working, even without it

Answer (score 0):

No idea where that specific error is coming from (it looks like it should actually be an error 1004), but I'm guessing just switching from using Activate and Select will resolve it.  Try the following:

```
'Set source workbook
Set FonteB = ActiveWorkbook
'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub
If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
'Set targetworkbook
Set FonteA = Workbooks.Open(vFile)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = FonteB.Worksheets("USD - SCHEDULE A")
lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

For Each rCell In ws.Cells.CurrentRegion
    If rCell.Font.Color = lColor Then
        If rColored Is Nothing Then
            Set rColored = rCell
        Else
            Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @Ygor - Do either of the Workbooks have references to other workbooks or each other?

Comment: No relation with each other. One of them has link to other workbook, but it is the target workbook.

Comment: @Ygor - Pretty sure that's your underlying issue - the target workbook is trying to connect to the source workbook (which is running code so isn't available to respond).